# Show function for polymorphic type

Tags: haskell, types, tree, polymorphism

I'm trying to define the Show function for the polymorphic Tree type. Could anyone help me?

```
import Char

data Tree t =
    NilT |
    Node t (Tree t) (Tree t)

class Mar t where
    maior :: t -> String

instance Mar Tree where
    maior (NilT) = "a" 
    maior (Node t a b) = "b"

instance Show Tree where
    show = maior
```

Thanks a Lot!

---

Solution (given by ivanm):

```
import Char

data Tree t =
    NilT |
    Node t (Tree t) (Tree t)

class Mar t where
    maior :: t -> String

instance Mar (Tree t) where
    maior (NilT) = "a" 
    maior (Node t a b) = "b"

instance Show (Tree t) where
    show = maior
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any particular reason that you aren't using `deriving Show`?  The `Show` and `Read` classes are meant to provide really basic serialisation/deserialisation which (usually) produce valid Haskell code.

But for what you want, I think the error is going back to your `Mar` class.  As defined, the instance is for kind `* -> *` (e.g. `Maybe` as opposed to `Maybe Int`).  What you probably meant is to have `instance Mar (Tree t) where ...`.

Comment: thanks for the shot, but it still giving me the same error (the one you mentioned) =/

Answer (score 1):

```
data Tree t =
    NilT |
    Node t (Tree t) (Tree t)
    deriving Show
```

Comment: I tried that, it still giving me an error message. Just to make clear, I want to override the show function.