# Class Instances and ambiguous occurence in Haskell

Tags: haskell, instance, ambiguous

Here is the code:

```
data Tree t = NilT
            | Node t (Tree t) (Tree t)

instance Show (Tree t) where
  show NilT = ""
  show Node t l r = (show t) ++ ", " ++ (show l) ++ ", " ++ (show r)
```

how to use "show" in "t show" with the default setting and use "show" with the tree data with the definition given by myself?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  It looks suspiciously similar to the recent questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478878/show-function-for-polymorphic-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479252/how-to-define-that-a-generic-type-is-printable

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `show t`, you must add the constraint `Show t` to your instance definition.

```
instance Show t => Show (Tree t) where
    show NilT = ""
    show (Node t l r) = show t ++ ", " ++ show l ++ ", " ++ show r
```

You were also missing parenthesis around your pattern `Node t l r`, and I removed the parenthesis around the calls to `show`, as they were redundant since function application already has the highest precedence.

Comment: You also might want to look at `hlint` which does some parentheses-fixing stuff for you (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note: There is a function `Data.List.intersperse` for putting a value between list elements.

```
show (Node t l r) = concat $ intersperse ", " [show t, show l, show r]
```

Or shorter, as hammar pointed out:

```
show (Node t l r) = intercalate ", " [show t, show l, show r]
```

Unfortunately you can't write `map show [t, l, r]`, as the list elements need to have a unique type.

Comment: There is also `Data.List.intercalate`, which also concatenates the result.

Comment: Oh thanks, I was already wondering, as I saw it for `Text` and `ByteString`.